# unable to enter credentials in input box in iframe (i.e cross domain) for safari browser through java selenium

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver, safaridriver

As part of our test scenario, there is a 3Dsecure window where I need to enter username, password and click submit button.

This works fine for chrome browser with java and selenium webdriver.

```
driver.switchTo().frame(By.id("ThreeDSecureIframe");
Then I type the user credentials and click submit button
```

However while running the test in safari, it does not recognise the username and password input boxes in the iframe. Is there any workaround with javascript etc?

The both parent and iframe are in different domain.(i.e parent url :- https://test.demo.com and iframe url :- https://adyen.com)
If you append the relative url mentioned in src of iframe to the parent url then it would redirect to `adyen.com` . There you can enter user credentials however once you click submit then you would miss the transactionId so you won't return back to the parent url)

```
<iframe id="ThreeDSecureIframe" src="/threedsecure/TriggerPostTo3Ds?clientPaymentTransactionId=7123456-">
  <input type="text" id="username">
```

While trying with javascript in the console, it complains about cross domain security.

> iOS safari as Appium error: An unknown server-side error occurred
>   while processing the command. Original error: Error while executing
>   atom: SecurityError (DOM Exception 18): Blocked a frame with origin
>   "test.abc.com" from accessing a frame with origin "test.xyz.com".
>   Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

[image]

Comment: Any answer to this please

Comment: Please add your code showing the credentials input and the exception output.

Comment: @pburgr updated the description with necessary details you asked for

Comment: You've mentioned the error when trying in console. When trying with the Selenium code, what is the error?

Comment: If I use selenium inbuilt methods like switchTo and sendKeys for username and password then it does not recognise that element ' Waiting for 'presence of element located by'. However if I use the javascript then it gives the DOM exception of cross domain.

Comment: @demouser123 please let me know if you need more info

Comment: Any update on this please

Comment: any update on this please

Comment: I'm facing a similar situation. I think it might be browser issue not allowing cross-domain JavaScript requests. I'm still searching to see if there's a solution to this.